# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sortable does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code in controller, am trying to sort columns in view file by just clicking on corresponding column name

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Service;
use DB;
use JsValidator;
use Validator;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Libraries\GlobalHelpers;
use App\Libraries\ImageHelpers;
use Auth;
use Response;


class ServicesController extends Controller
{

    protected $serviceValidationRules = [
        'service_name' => 'required'
    ];


    public function index()
    {
        $services = Service::all()->sortable()->get();
        return view('services.index')->with('services', $services);
    }
?>
```

Am getting following error

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sortable does not exist.
```

Kindly help me to resolve

Comment: Isn't that a separate package? In that case your model should extend the package's model class

Comment: because there is no `sortable()` method on Collection. Are you using package `eloquent-sortable` or `column-sortable`?

Comment: coloumn-sortable